# Replace strings in a pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, text

**Background**

I have the following sample `df` that contains `PHYSICIAN` in the `Text` column followed by the physician name (all names below are made up)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['PHYSICIAN: Jon J Smith was here today', 
                                   'And Mary Lisa Rider found here', 
                                   'Her PHYSICIAN: Jane A Doe is also here',
                                ' She was seen by  PHYSICIAN: Tom Tucker '], 

                      'P_ID': [1,2,3,4],
                      'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']

                     })

#rearrange columns
df = df[['Text','N_ID', 'P_ID']]
df

                                     Text         N_ID  P_ID
0   PHYSICIAN: Jon J Smith was here today           A1  1
1   And Mary Lisa Rider found here                  A2  2
2   Her PHYSICIAN: Jane A Doe is also here          A3  3
3   She was seen by PHYSICIAN: Tom Tucker           A4  4
```

**Goal**

1) Replace the names that follow the word `PHYSICIAN` (e.g. `PHYSICIAN: Jon J Smith`)  with `PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK**`

2) Create a new column named `Text_Phys`

**Desired Output**

```
                                  Text            N_ID P_ID  Text_Phys
0   PHYSICIAN: Jon J Smith was here today           A1  1   PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK** was here today
1   And Mary Lisa Rider found here                  A2  2   And Mary Lisa Rider found here
2   Her PHYSICIAN: Jane A Doe is also here          A3  3   Her PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK** is also here
3   She was seen by PHYSICIAN: Tom Tucker           A4  4   She was seen by PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK**
```

I have tried the following

1) `df['Text_Phys'] = df['Text'].replace(r'ABC.*', 'ABC: ***BLOCK***', regex=True)`

2) `df['Text_Phys'] = df['Text'].replace(r'ABC\s+', 'ABC: ***BLOCK***', regex=True)`

But they don't seem to quite work

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Comment: It should be working as `df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace(r'PHYSICIAN', 'PHYSICIAN: ***PHI***', regex=True)` and  `df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace(r'Physician', 'Physician: ***PHI***', regex=True)`

Comment: I tried but that doesn't quite work

Comment: How about `import re`  then `df['Text_Phys'] = df['Text'].str.replace('PHYSICIAN', 'PHYSICIAN: ***PHI***', flags=re.I)` but it will make the case in upper. However, earlier works fine for me, What version of pandas you are using.

Comment: how do you identify which part of the text is the name of the physician?

Comment: That did not quite work either.

Comment: @AndyL. The part of the text comes directly right after the name `Physician:` There isn't really another way in the actual data that I am taking this from

Comment: But, your desired output is `PHYSICIAN: **PHI** was here today`. It means you only replace a part of the string after  `PHYSICIAN: `

Comment: yeah exactly. And the length of words after the word `PHYSICIAN` is difficult to say because the length of names vary. But I see your point, and how this will be a bit difficult because of this

Comment: I have updated my question to make a bit simpler

Comment: It is easy to get the substring part after `PHYSICIAN: `. However, It is almost impossible to identify `Jon J Smith`, `Jane A Doe`, and `Tom Tucker` within the subtring. How do you know they are the names to replace unless you have some rules to identify them?

Comment: yes, good point. I may have to think about this a bit more and see if I can find a way to identify the names first and then alter them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try this: Use regex to define the words you want to match and where
>   you want to stop the search ( you could generate a list of all words
>   occurring after "** " to further automate the code). instead of the
>   quick hard code I did "Found|was |is " for sake of time.

[image]

code below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['PHYSICIAN: Jon J Smith was here today', 
                                   'And his Physician: Mary Lisa Rider found here', 
                                   'Her PHYSICIAN: Jane A Doe is also here',
                                ' She was seen by  PHYSICIAN: Tom Tucker '], 

                      'P_ID': [1,2,3,4],
                      'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']

                     })

df = df[['Text','N_ID', 'P_ID']]
df
    Text    N_ID    P_ID
0   PHYSICIAN: Jon J Smith was here today   A1  1
1   And his Physician: Mary Lisa Rider found here   A2  2
2   Her PHYSICIAN: Jane A Doe is also here  A3  3
3   She was seen by PHYSICIAN: Tom Tucker   A4  4

word_before = r'PHYSICIAN:'
words_after = r'.*?(?=found |was |is )'
words_all =r'PHYSICIAN:[\w\s]+'

import re

pattern = re.compile(word_before+words_after, re.IGNORECASE)
pattern2 = re.compile(words_all, re.IGNORECASE)

for i in range(len(df['Text'])):
    df.iloc[i,0] = re.sub(pattern,"PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK** ", df["Text"][i])
    if 'PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK**' not in df.iloc[i,0]:
        df.iloc[i,0] = re.sub(pattern2,"PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK** ", df["Text"][i])

df
    Text    N_ID    P_ID
0   PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK** was here today A1  1
1   And his PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK** found here A2  2
2   Her PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK** is also here   A3  3
3   She was seen by PHYSICIAN: **BLOCK**    A4  4
```